# Luke 21:33: How can heaven pass away, when the Lord's prayer states: "Our Father who art in Heaven"?

Tags: matthew

How can heaven pass away, when the Lord's prayer states: "Our Father who art in Heaven"?

> Luke 21:33 Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never
>   pass away.

Comment: Why do you seem to assume that a word can only have one meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: God is a spirit, so He is not confined to one realm. Therefore, the heavens can pass away without affecting God.

The long answer:
God is a spirit. From the Westminster Shorter Catechism with Scripture Proofs:

> Q4:What is God?
>   A:God is a Spirit, infinite, eternal, and unchangeable, in his being, >wisdom, power, holiness, justice, goodness, and truth.
>
> 1.God [is] a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship [him] in spirit >and in truth. (John 4:24, KJV).
>   2.Canst thou by searching find out God? canst thou find out the Almighty >unto perfection? (Job 11:7, KJV).
>   3.Before the mountains were brought forth, or ever thou hadst formed the >earth and the world, even from everlasting to everlasting, thou [art] God. >(Psalms 90:2, KJV).
>   4.Every good gift and every perfect gift is from above, and cometh down >from the Father of lights, with whom is no variableness, neither shadow of >turning. (James 1:17, KJV).
>   5.And God said unto Moses, I AM THAT I AM: and he said, Thus shalt thou say >unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto you. (Exodus 3:14, KJV).
>   6.Great [is] our Lord, and of great power: his understanding [is] infinite. >(Psalms 147:5, KJV).
>   7.And the four beasts had each of them six wings about [him]; and [they >were] full of eyes within: and they rest not day and night, saying, Holy, >holy, holy, Lord God Almighty, which was, and is, and is to come. >(Revelation 4:8, KJV).
>   8.Who shall not fear thee, O Lord, and glorify thy name? for [thou] only >[art] holy: (Revelation 15:4, KJV).
>   9.And the LORD passed by before him, and proclaimed, The LORD, The LORD >God, merciful and gracious, longsuffering, and abundant in goodness and >truth, Keeping mercy for thousands, forgiving iniquity and transgression >and sin, and that will by no means clear [the guilty]; visiting the >iniquity of the fathers upon the children, and upon the children's >children, unto the third and to the fourth [generation]. (Exodus 34:6-7, >KJV).

As a Spirit, God is not confined to one place.He is in heaven, as you mentioned. The Bible says more specifically that  Jesus is in heaven, seated at the right hand of the Father.

> that he worked in Christ when he raised him from the dead and seated him at >his right hand in the heavenly places,
>   (Ephesians 1:20 ESV)

However, God is also with us everywhere.

> Where shall I go from your Spirit?
>   Or where shall I flee from your presence?
>   If I ascend to heaven, you are there!
>   If I make my bed in Sheol, you are there!
>   If I take the wings of the morning
>   and dwell in the uttermost parts of the sea,
>   even there your hand shall lead me,
>   and your right hand shall hold me.
>   If I say, “Surely the darkness shall cover me,
>   and the light about me be night,”
>   even the darkness is not dark to you;
>   the night is bright as the day,
>   for darkness is as light with you.
>   (Psalm 139:7-12 ESV)

Since God is not bound to any one realm, it makes sense that He will not be affected when the heavens pass away, even though He is there. You may ask about the saints who have gone before us. They are spirits, also, since they haven't yet been given resurrected in body:

> But in fact Christ has been raised from the dead, the firstfruits of those >who have fallen asleep. For as by a man came death, by a man has come also >the resurrection of the dead. For as in Adam all die, so also in Christ >shall all be made alive. But each in his own order: Christ the firstfruits, >then at his coming those who belong to Christ. Then comes the end, when he delivers the kingdom to God the Father after destroying every rule and every authority and power. For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet. The last enemy to be destroyed is death.

(1 Corinthians 15:20-26 ESV)

Revelation 21
 1 And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away ; and there was no more sea.
2 And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, thanks for contributing - this is an excellent first answer! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)